# How to delay only one portion of code without delaying the entire application. (Python)

Tags: python, delay

So I'm modifying a game. When you hit the spacebar, the little ship you control fires a shot. The game can be easily abused by just spamming the spacebar. I tried using time.sleep, but that pauses the entire game -- which I don't want. I'm a fairly novice programmer.

Comment: Record the time the last shot was fired, then compare that time to the time of the new spacebar press. If it is less than a threshold you set, don't fire.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite unclear, please add some more information. A few lines of source code are often better than 1000 words :)

Comment: Thanks C.B. Sorry about the unclearness ByteHamster. Sadly, I don't have the code with me right now. I am a student and I have to work off of this OLPC, which is stored at the school. I will try to post the source code @ 3:30 - 4:00 PM EST today.